# How do you invoke a method with the signature "public double getMedian(double[]list) {//code}"

Tags: java, methods, call

I want to invoke this method to get the median from an array. The method is declared as `public double getMedian(double[]list){//code}`.

I tried calling the method as `getMedian(double,list)` but I got an error. What would be the right way to call the method?

Here is the complete method:

```
public double getMedian(double[] list) {
    // calculate the length of the entries
    // create an iterator
    int factor = list.length - 1;
    double[] first = new double[(int) ((double) factor / 2)];
    double[] last = new double[first.length];
    double[] middleNumbers = new double[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        first[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int i = list.length; i > last.length; i--) {
        last[i] = list[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] != first[i] || list[i] != last[i])
            middleNumbers[i] = list[i];
    }

    if (list.length % 2 == 0) {
        double total = middleNumbers[0] + middleNumbers[1];
        return total / 2;
    } else {
        System.out.println(middleNumbers);
        return middleNumbers[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's asking for an array of double. "list" is just the name it's using for that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method takes an array of double values as a parameter. You would want to make an array of double and pass that:

```
double[] values = {0.1d, 0.3d, 0.5d, 1.0d, 1200.0d};        
double median = this.getMedian(values); // should return 0.5d
```

But the `getMedian` method has some logic errors that prevent it from working correctly. In particular, the second loop starts beyond the bounds of the array:

```
 for (int i = list.length; i > last.length; i--) {
     last[i] = list[i];
 }
```

Using my test data, `i` starts at `5` and counts down until `i` is greater than `5`, but the array only has elements indexed from `0` to `4`.

Comment: I see thank you for your help! I will mark it as answered since its leading me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its only asking for a double, list is what you just made the name of the array. You would need to do

```
getMedian(double[] doubleArray, List list)
```

To use 2 different types when its called.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (which includes arguably a more elegant, and working, version of getMedian):

```
public class Test 
{
    public double getMedian(double[] list)
    {
        double median = 0;

        if (list != null && (list.length > 0)) 
        {
            // Sort ascending
            Arrays.sort(list);

            int numItems = list.length;

            if ((numItems % 2) == 0)
            {
                // We have an even number of items - average the middle two
                int middleIndex = numItems / 2;
                double firstMiddleValue = list[middleIndex - 1];
                double secondMiddleValue = list[middleIndex];
                median = (firstMiddleValue + secondMiddleValue) / 2;
            } 
            else
            {
                // Odd number of items - pick the middle one
                median = list[(numItems / 2)];
            }
        }

        return median;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();

        double[] testValuesOfLengthOne = { 3.1415 };
        double[] testValuesEvenLength = {22.5, 14.33, 100.849, 44.259, 0.0, 145000.0};
        double[] testValuesOddLength = {22.5, 14.33, 100.849, 44.259, 0.0,  145000.0, -4.9};

        System.out.println("Median of " + Arrays.toString(testValuesOfLengthOne)    + " is " + t.getMedian(testValuesOfLengthOne));
        System.out.println("Median of " + Arrays.toString(testValuesEvenLength) + " is " + t.getMedian(testValuesEvenLength));
        System.out.println("Median of " + Arrays.toString(testValuesOddLength) + " is " + t.getMedian(testValuesOddLength));
    }
}
```

This gives you the following output:

```
Median of [3.1415] is 3.1415
Median of [22.5, 14.33, 100.849, 44.259, 0.0, 145000.0] is 33.3795
Median of [22.5, 14.33, 100.849, 44.259, 0.0, 145000.0, -4.9] is 22.5
```